# What is the difference between Microwave, Microwave Oven, and Oven?

Tags: oven, microwave

Some sites say that a "microwave" is **only** for heating or re-heating cooked food. Whereas, in "microwave ovens", you can microwave and bake. Is that true?

If it is, then why I can cook main course dishes (chicken, rice), soups, etc. in my microwave oven? I even have a recipe book with 100+ recipes using a microwave oven.

So, can someone please clear up this fog? What's the difference between Microwave and Oven and Microwave Oven?

Comment: I see on your profile that you're in India - note that the terms you're using in your question are probably used a bit differently in the rest of the world (or at least in the US).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First off, the terminology issue.

> So, can someone please clear up this fog? What's the difference between Microwave and Oven and Microwave Oven?

["Microwave" is just short for "microwave oven".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven) Both terms mean the same thing: an appliance that uses microwave radiation to heat food. Cooking food in this way is called "microwaving". An oven, on the other hand, has a heating element which heats the air inside, which then heats the food. Cooking food in this way is generally called "baking", though there are a lot of other things (e.g. roasting) you can also reasonably do in an oven.

So if all you have is a microwave, then all you can do is microwave (not bake). And if you have an oven, then you can bake (but of course you can't microwave).

There also exist combinations, which are capable of both microwaving *and* baking, i.e. they have a microwave emitter *and* a heating element. However, remember that in the US - and thus on much of the internet - something talking about a "microwave oven" likely does not mean this combination, but simply microwave heating. Names like "convection microwave oven with grill", "combination microwave/oven" *do* refer to these combinations, though. I've also seen "speed oven". You may sometimes have seen people referring to these combination microwave/ovens as a "microwave oven" (I think this may be common in Indian English), but that's really just imprecise language.

> Some sites say that a "microwave" is only for heating or re-heating cooked food. Whereas, in "microwave ovens", you can microwave and bake. Is that true?

It sounds like in this statement, "microwave oven" is careless language, referring to a combination microwave *and* oven. (It doesn't make any sense at all otherwise; the two things are the same thing, so of course you can do the same things in them.)

So the question is really, what can you do in a microwave vs an oven, or a combination microwave/oven?

It's true that microwaves are *mainly* used for reheating cooked food, and it's true that they can't actually bake. However, they can do a *lot* more than reheat food; there are a lot of kinds of cooking besides baking. For example, microwaves are *great* at simmering/boiling and steaming, and it doesn't matter if the food was cooked already or not. The recipes you're talking about are probably mostly in those kinds of categories, but if you're interested, [How do I know if a food or recipe can be made in a microwave oven?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/32121/1672) discusses in a bit more detail what works in microwaves.

The big things that you can do with ovens but not microwaves are the things that actually need the steady dry heat of baking. You can't bake bread or cookies or roast a chicken in a microwave. Microwaves hold in a lot of steam and don't get terribly hot, so you can't generally get things to brown or crisp up. They also don't really hold a temperature like you need for baking, they just pump more and more heat into the food.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Now I understand why it is called "convection." One more question: I have a microwave Oven. So I can bake in it, too. Right? Or will the baking be any different from that of an Oven?

Comment: @Mrstupid I'm pretty sure I covered that... do you have a microwave oven aka microwave? If so, you can only microwave, not bake. Or do you have a combination microwave and oven? If so, you can microwave and bake.

Comment: (Also, for the record, a convection oven is a specific kind of oven - it has a fan to move the air around, i.e. to force convection. Some combination microwave/ovens have this feature, and some don't.)

Comment: I have these four modes in the Microwave: Combination, Grill, Convection, Microwave.

Answer (score -3):

for clarity, a microwave oven is different from a microwave. Please be aware that a microwave oven can bake as much as you can with an oven. The fact is a microwave oven is a microwave convention which is a higher grade to a microwave. And in such, you can make brownies, cup cakes, pizza, bread, e.t.c in a microwave oven.

Comment: [Here](https://www.amazon.com/Toshiba-EM131A5C-SS-Microwave-Interior-Stainless/dp/B076VB5JFQ/) is the first search result for "microwave oven" on Amazon. Note that it doesn't do convection. Neither does [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Nostalgia-RMO7RR-Countertop-Microwave-Programmed/dp/B07S4WLBQD/) or [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Panasonic-Microwave-NN-SN686S-Countertop-Technology/dp/B01DEWZUG4/). I can understand your confusion, but the accepted answer from two years ago really is correct.